# Laravel 5.8 - How to protect Storage Directory from routing?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I'd like to protect my files inside Storage Directory, but when I accessing the storage directory from address bar, all of my storage files appear like this :
[image]

What I want is, if user inserting `/storage` keywords to the URL or address bar, it will redirected to 404 Page or somewhere else.

```
Route::get('/storage', function(){
  // What Should I do here?
});
```

Comment: Why would you have a get route to storage? If you don't have route for an url it will give you `404 Error` itself.

Comment: No, if I didn't create that route, it will show like the screenshot, not to 404.

Comment: where you put your storage directory in server? in public_html? or its on a server?

Comment: Put all your folders and files of public directory to public_html on the server.

Comment: I put it on public_html/member, the subdomain I have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your site's root directory is wrong.

The domain name should point to the **public** folder inside Laravel's root directory (*for a default configuration*).
This way your **storage** folder and all other directories stay outside and can not be reached using browser.

And it might be a good idea to disable directory indexing in your **Web server's configuration**. If using Apache - you can put the following option in to your **.htaccess** file:

```
Options -Indexes
```